# oracle date function to append month and year

Tags: sql, oracle, date, oracle10g

Hi have query like this now i want to append value in query  so tran_date is in Date time format in databases: so consider these two query

query 1:: i have to append value in date format but it not working ..how to pass year and month in date type::

```
select TRAN_DATE,
       trunc(nvl(SUM(SALES_VALUE), 0) + nvl(sum(total_sales), 0) -
             nvl(sum(net_sales), 0) + nvl(sum(discount), 0)) Sale
  from OUTLET_PAYMODE_REPORT_FACT A, OUTLET_DETAILS B
 WHERE A.OUTLET_ID = B.OUTLET_ID
   and SALES_VALUE > 0
   and to_date(TRAN_DATE, 'yyyy') = '2013'
   AND to_date(TRAN_DATE, 'MON') = 'APR'
    OR to_date(TRAN_DATE, 'yyyy') = '2013'
   AND to_date(TRAN_DATE, 'MON') = 'MAR'
 GROUP BY TRAN_DATE
```

query 2: its work but it is string format

```
select TRAN_DATE,
       trunc(nvl(SUM(SALES_VALUE), 0) + nvl(sum(total_sales), 0) -
             nvl(sum(net_sales), 0) + nvl(sum(discount), 0)) Sale
  from OUTLET_PAYMODE_REPORT_FACT A, OUTLET_DETAILS B
 WHERE A.OUTLET_ID = B.OUTLET_ID
   and SALES_VALUE > 0
   and (to_char(TRAN_DATE, 'yyyy') = '2013' AND
       to_char(TRAN_DATE, 'MON') = 'APR')
    OR (to_char(TRAN_DATE, 'yyyy') = '2013' AND
       to_char(TRAN_DATE, 'MON') = 'MAR')
 GROUP BY TRAN_DATE
```

Answer (score 0):

One of options is to use `BETWEEN` condition with `DATETIME` datatype columns:

```
select TRAN_DATE,
       trunc(nvl(SUM(SALES_VALUE), 0) + nvl(sum(total_sales), 0) -
             nvl(sum(net_sales), 0) + nvl(sum(discount), 0)) Sale
  from OUTLET_PAYMODE_REPORT_FACT A, OUTLET_DETAILS B
 WHERE A.OUTLET_ID = B.OUTLET_ID
   and SALES_VALUE > 0
   and TRAN_DATE between to_date('01.03.2013', 'dd.mm.yyyy') and
                         to_date('30.04.2013', 'dd.mm.yyyy')
 GROUP BY TRAN_DATE;
```